# ClosedXml "display value" and "real value"

Tags: excel, closedxml

I am not sure if there is such a thing in Excel (xlsx) file, but if you see the screenshot

[image]

I can type in certain format of value what is displayed in cell is different from formula bar.

But if I use ClosedXml to create Excel,

```
currentCell.Value = "1-Jan-2017";
currentCell.DataType = XLCellValues.DateTime;
```

The file generated by the code looks like (just see the last cell)

[image]

Is there a way I can use ClosedXml to achieve what I need? Our business person likes to see the value "1-Jan-2017".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That format seems to be number 15 from the predefined date formats in Excel (see [here](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/NumberFormatId-Lookup-Table)). You can use the following to set it

```
currentCell.Style.DateFormat.SetNumberFormatId(15);
```

For other (not predefined) formats you can also use something like

```
currentCell.Style.DateFormat.SetDateFormat("d-mmm-yy");
```